# Antlr Expression comparing two columns in a table

Tags: antlr

I am quite new to ANtlr and writing expression. I have a  table with two columns of string ColA and ColB. Im tryng to run this expression using ANtlr: [ColA] == [ColB]
Doing so gives an expression error. Is comparing two columns possible using ANtlr if so can someone please show me how.

Comment: Please post your grammar and the exact error message you get.

Comment: Note, the name should be "ANTLR" ("*An*other *t*ool for *l*anguage *r*ecognition", https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/spe.4380250705 https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2714064.2660202) or "Antlr" (the proper noun avoiding the upper case lettering), but not "ANtlr". I have also seen in other SO questions the name as "AntLR", incorrectly assuming that it is an LR-parser generator.